# Verbs and Phrase

Tags: verbs, transitivity

My question is related to verb and phrases.

I've written the following question and confused whether the sentence is correct or not.

> The research on fatal heart attacks and stroke **makes** physicians **believe** *that obesity is a main common factor in all these incurable health diseases*.

Is the above sentence correct?

If it is not correct then please inform the mistakes.

If it is correct then my confusion is as make and believe both are transitive verbs so I'm confused in the role of **make** and **believe** and the part of the sentence starting with that.

**makes** is acting as a transitive verb and physicians as its subject. 
The part of the sentence after word physicians needs to clarify. Is the phrase "*believe that obesity as a main common factor in all these incurable health diseases*" is also acting as noun phrase.? or **believe** is acting as a verb transitive and rest of the part of sentence is acting as a subject for believe?

Can we use two verbs together as a single verb?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I edited the question. I'm confused on the usage of make and believe simultaneously in a single sentence as both are transitive verb.

Comment: Most importantly, please understand that your example is _not_ a complete sentence in English. That should be addressed first.

Comment: @P.E.Dant It has subject verb and object. It looks to me a complete sentence.

Comment: @RaheelBari "that obesity as a main common factor in all these incurable health diseases" doesn't have a verb.

Answer (score 1):

> {something} *makes* a physician *believe* {something}.
>
> {something} *causes* a physician *to believe* {something}.

You can see that the choice of verb (makes, causes) has an impact on the verb form that follows after **physician**.

In neither case is **believe** a finite form of the verb, as we can see from the lack of number agreement ("a physician believe").

To take another example:

> The interrogators made him confess (the crime).
>
> The interrogators got him to confess (the crime).

I believe "(to) confess (the crime)" is being called a *noun clause* these days.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. You make my day. The choice of verb obviously is not good enough. Could you add one more point. Is it allowable to use two verbs in this manner  (both are transitive) in any case?.

Comment: The initial verb must be of the type of verb that licenses a non-finite object complement consisting of a noun clause. It cannot be just any transitive verb. *I urged him to confess* would work, or told, implored, begged, entreated, required, hammered, nagged, etc. But  *I painted him to confess*, though transitive, would not do.

Comment: The object complement of such a verb will be an *action*. *They told us to go.*

Comment: That is very helpful indeed. What do you say on this sentence. I rewrite the sentence. After years of research on the cases of heart attack and strokes, physicians finds obesity as a common significant factor in such cases. Or  After years of research on the cases of heart attack and strokes, physicians finds common significant of obesity in such cases.

Comment: After years of research on heart attack and stroke, physicians have found obesity to be a significant factor common to both.

Comment: Thankyou :) I got it...will definitely going to help me alot. Have a good day

Comment: One last thing, How English learner can learn to use the correct type of object complement (infinitive, gerund, that clause). Is there any simple guide line or you need to practice and memorize it. Thank you.

Comment: Speak with native speakers as often as possible. Read many English texts from reputable sources. Watch English movies and TV. Study and memorization.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the given sentance:

- The research on fatal heart attacks and stroke makes physicians believe that obesity is a main common factor in all these incurable health diseases.

The word choice could be improved.

A person has (or suffers from) a `stroke` but the research is on `strokes`. It is not clear whether the research covers non-fatal strokes. It may be better to clarify with `... on fatal heart attacks and fatal strokes ...`. If the research is on non-fatal strokes and fatal heart attacks then swapping the order may be better, thus: `... on strokes and fatal heart attacks ...`

The phrase `a main common factor in all` may be better as `a significant common factor in all` or as `a significant factor common to all`. Although if obesity is the main factor then the phrase `the main factor common to all` may be correct.

The words `incurable health diseases` are wrong; I would suggest either `incurable health conditions` or `incurable diseases`. You may need a medical expert to distinguish between a `condition` and a `disease`.

I would question the use of `incurable`. Many people recover from heart attacks and strokes and live happily for several decades. This thought makes me wonder about the word `fatal`. If the research is only about the fatalities then I would replace `incurable health diseases` with the single word `cases`. If the research is about all heart attacks and strokes then the sentance might finish with `the main factor common to many cases`. I wrote `many cases` because the `all` in the original applies to the two conditions, not to the people suffering from them.

Comment: The choice of words are not good enough. Thankyou for the detail response.